# Maximum likelihood estimator is sample mean or minimum ordered statistic?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3....X_n$ be a random sample from a population having probability density function
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\theta} e^\frac{-(x-\theta)}{\theta} ;x\geq\theta$$

where $\theta\in(0,\infty)$. Find the MLE of $\theta$.

In this question when i followed normal method of finding MLE(taking log likelihood differentiating with respect to $\theta$)I found $\hat\theta =\bar x$. 
But like in uniform distribution case we have here parameter dependent on $x$  . Now i am not sure if MLE is $\bar x$ or $x_{(1)}$.

Comment: Any maximum likelihood estimator cannot be greater than $x_{(1)}$ here as  that would lead to a likelihood of $0$.  It might be clearer if you wrote $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\theta} e^\frac{-(x-\theta)}{\theta} I_{x \ge \theta}$ for all $x$ where  $I_{x \ge \theta}$ is an indicator function

Comment: Likelihood in this  $0 \leq \theta  \leq x_{(1)}$ part will still give $\bar x $ i don't get it .

Comment: @Damn1o1 No, because $x_{(1)}$ is always less than or equal to $\bar x$

Comment: @Henry After writing first comment you never comeback.

Comment: Damn1o1 - I am not permanently on the site.  $\hat{\theta} = \bar x$ will have a zero likelihood because it is almost surely greater than $x_{(1)}$.  @heropup gave the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta} \exp\left( - \left(\tfrac{x}{\theta} - 1 \right) \right) \mathbb 1 (x \ge \theta > 0) = \frac{e}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta} \mathbb 1 (x \ge \theta > 0).$$  Hence the likelihood given a sample $\boldsymbol x$ is proportional to $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = \theta^{-n} e^{-n \bar x/\theta} \mathbb 1(x_{(1)} \ge  \theta > 0).$$  The log-likelihood is $$\ell(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = \begin{cases} - n \log \theta - \frac{n \bar x}{\theta}, & 0 < \theta \le x_{(1)} \\ -\infty, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$   But since the critical point satisfying $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} = 0 = -\frac{n}{\theta} \left( 1 - \frac{\bar x}{\theta}\right)$$ is $\theta = \bar x$, and 
 $$\bar x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{(1)} = x_{(1)},$$ with equality if and only if $x_i = x_{(1)}$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we conclude that the log-likelihood has no critical point in $\theta \in (0, x_{(1)})$; hence it is maximized when $\theta = x_{(1)}$ as $\partial \ell/\partial \theta < 0$ for all such $\theta$ (i.e., it is strictly decreasing).

Comment: Thank you so much i get it now.

Comment: So $\bar x  $ is nothing but $x_{(1)}$ because there nothing else except $x_{(1)}$ according to $\theta \in (0, x_{(1)})$. I am thinking it this way did i follow it right?

Comment: Not really.  Unless all of your observations are the same (which for such a distribution happens with zero probability for a sample size greater than 1), the sample mean is always greater than the minimum order statistic, hence it cannot be chosen as the MLE.  The likelihood is zero that $\theta$ is greater than the minimum order statistic, because you cannot choose the parameter to exceed a value that you observed.